# Installed Python 3.8 on Ubuntu, but it's not the default

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have downloaded Python 3.8 on my Ubuntu 16.04 and if i write `python3.8` it shows it is present, but when I write `python --version` I am getting my old Python version which was 3.5

Answer (score 25):

Set an alias:

```
alias python=python3.8
```

Then running `python` in Bash will run `python3.8`.

To make the change permanent, put the alias line in `~/.bashrc`. It will take effect when you open Bash.

---

### Symlinks

#### Why not symlink `/usr/bin/python` to `python3.8`?

Ubuntu follows [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) which says the `python` command should point to Python 2. However an alias works since it only affects your shell. It doesn't even affect scripts you write, meaning if you want a script to run in Python 3.8, you'll have to write it explicitly in the shebang, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python3.8` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

#### Why not at least symlink `/usr/bin/python3` to `python3.8`?

Some things will break since there are version-specific libraries. For example `_gi` is not available for Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 16.04, so Gnome Terminal will not open. See [Gnome terminal will not start](https://askubuntu.com/q/880188/301745) on Ask Ubuntu for an example.

---

### More details

- [How to make 'python' program command execute Python 3?](https://askubuntu.com/q/320996/301745) on Ask Ubuntu

Comment: Also Ubuntu comes with a handful tool, so you can quickly workaround this:
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3

Comment: and: `alias pip='pip3.8'`

Comment: @forzagreen Actually, I'd probably recommend a virtualenv if you need to use Pip, since in Ubuntu, it's not necessarily installed alongside Python, and in my experience it's very finicky.

Comment: Another remark: alias doesn't go along with python virtual environments. If you activate a venv, the "python" command will be interpreted as an alias, not as the venv's local python. (check with `which python`)

Answer (score 3):

Everything depends on how you installed the python3.8.
Many methods wouldn't update default symlinks for you.

If you do something like:
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python` and run `python --version` afterward it should solve your issue.

If you python3.8 binary is not in `/usr/bin/python3.8` update your symlink path accordingly.

Keep in mind that some apps dependent on specific features of the lower python version might not work correctly. With Python3 the probability is low though.

Comment: I wouldn't use this personally, since Ubuntu follows [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) which says the `python` command should point to Python 2. However an alias would work. I'll post my own answer.

Comment: @ArtyomKovalyov I have ruined my distribution using this approach!

Comment: You can't ruin a distro like this. Reverse your symlinks and be good.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is **sudo apt install python-is-python3** - it effectively does a symlink, but it also keeps pace with future updates; so if your ubuntu distribution moves to say Python 3.9, the manual symlink will no longer work, but the package makes sure it is still valid.

credit to https://askubuntu.com/a/1272899/1055134