# "python3" is executing "python3.8" instead of "python3.9"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu and I just updated my python3 from 3.8 to 3.9 but when I'm running Python3 on terminal it opens the
3.8 version and not the 3.9.

How can I change this? thanks a lot.
[python3 --version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt3jx.png)

Comment: I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59273106/4518341) that covers a very similar situation.

Comment: @wjandrea Note that the answer is somewhat outdated: Python2.7 is not included in ubuntu20.04, and there is specifically a package `python-is-python3`.

Comment: @wjandrea Also, I would argue that it is version specify. (Since you removed the tag)

Comment: I think since 3.9 python is just `python` (not `python3`)

Comment: @MegaIng Good point about Python 2. I'm aware of that but not too familiar. Could you explain how the question is specific to Python 3.9?

Comment: @wjandrea Because this is specifically about the difference between python3.8 and python3.9.

Comment: @MegaIng Is that any different than the difference between 3.7 and 3.8, or 3.6 and 3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. `python3.8` is a distribution used by other programs on Ubuntu, which expects that dependencies on `python3-<package name>` install in a way that `python3` can import them. If you change the linkage, any number of (possible important) packages might break. Just use `python3.9` explicit.